# i want to get a parameter with button in xaml

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

i want to delete or update rows of a list view by the primary key which is Label

```
 <Label Grid.Column="1"
               Grid.Row="0"
               Text="{Binding Label}"
               FontSize="20"
               TextColor="Black"
               Margin="0,10"
               FontFamily="Comfortaa-Light"/>

 <Label Grid.Column="2"
               Grid.Row="1"
               Text="{Binding Todo}" 
               FontSize="20"
               TextColor="Black"
               Margin="0,10,0,0"
               FontFamily="Comfortaa-Light"
               HorizontalOptions="Start"
               VerticalOptions="Center"/>
 <ImageButton Grid.Column="2"
                       Grid.Row="0"
                       HorizontalOptions="End"
                       VerticalOptions="End"
                       Source="plus.png"
                       Margin="9"
                       BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                          Clicked="AddReminder"
                here parameter{{Binding Label}}                  />
```

I need help and thank you

Comment: are you using MVVM or you want it in code behind?

Comment: i'm using MVVM to show data in list view and i want to know how to pass a parameter in the button function i need the data "Label" from the list view

Comment: where do you need the data in view model or AddReminder Event? Can you share code of AddReminder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you had used Data-binding(MVVM) .It would better to handle the logic by using **Command** . In addition, we could pass the text of label(or the whole model) instead of the Label itself .

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="App11.MainPage"
             x:Name="page"> // set the name of the page
```

```
<ImageButton Grid.Column="2"
                       Grid.Row="0"
                       HorizontalOptions="End"
                       VerticalOptions="End"
                       Source="plus.png"
                       Margin="9"
                       BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                       Command="{Binding Source={x:Reference page},Path=BindingContext.xxxCommand}}"  
                       CommandParameter="{Binding .}"
                     />
```

#### in your viewmodel

```
public ICommand xxxCommand { get; set; }
```

```
xxxCommand = new Command((arg)=> {

  //var model = arg as YourModel;
  // you can get the text of label from the model and do something you want 
});
```

Comment: please i need to more understand because u'm beginner in xamarin this line to put the parameter that i need in "AddReminder" right ?

Comment: Clicked="AddReminder" the function in the view model

Comment: `Command="{Binding Source={x:Reference page},Path=BindingContext.xxxCommand}}"  
 CommandParameter="{Binding .}"` the first for the function and teh second for parameter but i don't know how to use it